# Postfix mail server acting as an open relay

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I'm trying to get postfix to work with mail clients (thunderbird / outlook), but the only way I can achieve it at the moment is by turning the mail server into an open relay, which is very bad, obviously.

When I set the 'mynetworks' parameter to '127.0.0.0/8', the server is secure, but I can only access it via webmail. If I try to connect to it through thunderbird I get 5.7.1 relay access denied errors.

When I set the 'mynetworks' parameter to '0.0.0.0/0', it works with thunderbird, but also acts as an open relay.

To try and fix this, I set up sasl auth, but I can't get it working properly. Here are my postconf settings:

```
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
   reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
   reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
   reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous noplaintext
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

I've tried a plethora of different settings but I'm getting nowhere. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you are using the ipaddress to connect to your POSTFIX server from Thunderbird?

Comment: What errors do you get in your mail server log when you close the open relaying off and try to send mail from Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
# SASL support
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

#RESTRICCIONES DEL REMITENTE
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks,
     reject_unknown_sender_domain,
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     reject_unlisted_sender

#RESTRICCIONES DEL DESTINO 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks, 
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     reject_unauth_destination,
     reject_unlisted_recipient,
     warn_if_reject reject_unknown_client

# TLS Support
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/my.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/mycert.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

The `smtpd_client_restrictions` is meant for *all* clients connecting to the server, not just clients that try to relay mail through the mailserver, but also for local delivery. To have the mail server accept mail for all clients for local delivery, but require authentication for relaying you have to specify the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` option.

I have the following config:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.100.0.11/32 10.100.2.11/32 [2001:470:xxxx::11]/128 [2001:470:xxxx:4::11]/128
[...]
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                               check_relay_domains,
                               reject_unauth_pipelining,
                               reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                               reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                               permit_sasl_authenticated,
                               reject_unauth_destination,
                               reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
                               check_policy_service unix:private/spfcheck,
                               permit
[...]
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

(I don't have a `smtpd_client_restrictions` section)